# avp.com scan pipe error when using ssh -n command?

Tags: windows, bash, unix, batch-file, ssh

i have the following case :-

i design :-

1- `file.bat` on windows 2003

2- `file2.sh` on unix-aix

`file2.bash` call `file.bat` and  `file.bat` receve path from `file2.bash` and `file.bash` return a value to `file2.bat`  .... when i execute this from my servers all thing good 
but when i call this from my website (PHP) the following error appear :-
`ERROR: API    = ReadConsole.
   error code = 109.
   message    = The pipe has been ended.`
i think (PHP) close the stream between windows and unix before windows write a value to unix

**after tracing the code `avp.com scan` accoure this error why ???!!!!**

the same error appear when I use `ssh -n user host`

how i can solve this problem

**file.bat :-**

`@echo off`

`"C:\Program Files\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Anti-Virus 6.0 for Windows Servers\avp.com" %1 /i2 > NUL 2>&1`

`set /a error = %errorlevel%`

`::error in executing avp.com command`

`if %error% equ 9009  goto :something_error`

`:: Infected`

`if not exist %1 goto :file_not_exist`

`:: if error grater than zero go to label something_error otherwise [error=0] go to label valu_0`

`if %error% gtr 0 (goto :something_error) else (goto :value_0)`

`:something_error`

`:: There is threat`

`if %error% equ 102 exit /b 1`

`:: Infected`

`if %error% equ 101 exit /b 2`

`:: Missing parameters`

`if %error% equ 1 exit /b 4`

`:: Anti-Virus application error`

`if %error% equ 3 exit /b 3`

`if %error% equ 4 exit /b 3`

`if %error% equ 9009 exit /b 3`

`:: Abnormal error`

`if %error% equ 2 exit /b 7`

`:value_0`

`::No threat`

`exit /b 0`

`:file_not_exist`

`:: Infected`

`exit /b 2`

**file2.sh:-**

`PRIMARY_SERVER_NAME="1.1.1.1"`

`PRIMARY_SERVER_USERNAME="Administrator"`

`BACKUP_SERVER_NAME="1.2.5.2"`

`BACKUP_SERVER_USERNAME="Administrator"`

`LOG_FILE="/opt/payone/antivirus/log/scan.log"`

`COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS_UNIX_FORMAT="/cygdrive/d/payone"`

`SCAN_BATCH_FILE_WINDOWS="d:\\\payone\\\scan.bat"`

`COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS_WINDOWS_FORMAT="d:\\\payone"`

`# $1 = name of the uploaded file`

`if [ -f "$1" ];`

`then`

`scp -r /$1/ ${PRIMARY_SERVER_USERNAME}`

`@${PRIMARY_SERVER_NAME}:${COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS_UNIX_FORMAT}`

`if [ $? -eq 0 ];`

`then`

`ssh -l ${PRIMARY_SERVER_USERNAME}`

`${PRIMARY_SERVER_NAME} 'cmd /c '$SCAN_BATCH_FILE_WINDOWS' '$COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS_WINDOWS_FORMAT'/'$x''`

`else`

`scp -r /$1/ ${BACKUP_SERVER_USERNAME }`

`@${BACKUP_SERVER_NAME}:${COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS_UNIX_FORMAT}`

`ssh -l ${BACKUP_SERVER_USERNAME}`
 `${BACKUP_SERVER_NAME} 'cmd /c '$SCAN_BATCH_FILE_WINDOWS' '$COPY_FILE_TO_WINDOWS_WINDOWS_FO`RMAT'/'$1''`

`fi`

`error_code=$?`

`echo "$(date +%c)       $1      error code=$error_code">> ${LOG_FILE}`

`exit $error_code`

`else`

`echo "$(date +%c)       $1      error code = 5  " >> ${LOG_FILE}`

`exit 5`

`fi`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your keys are set-up correctly, you will still need to interact with `ssh` the very first time you connect with a host. You may get a prompt like:

>
The authenticity of host 'whatever(123.45.67.89)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 12:34:56:78:9a:bc:de:f0:11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Have you connected manually to each host before you try to connect automatically?

Comment: yes i connect manually to each file but after trace error i found command "avp.com scan" from kaspersky command line interface cause this error ..do you anything about it